# mercurial: test whether a branch contains a changeset

Tags: mercurial

I wonder whether there is a mercurial command/extension that just tests whether a given changeset is in a branch. The command would be something like:

```
hg contains [-r branch] changeset_id
```

and should check whether the given changeset is in the current/given branch, returning just "Yes" or "No".

I know about the "debugancestor" command, but a "Yes/No" answer is way easier to read.

And if there is, is it possible to check for transplanted changesets as well?

EDIT: The scenario is located in a repo where named branches have multiple heads. Lets say a branch is named "dev-X", having more than 1 head and a longer history, too long at least to track it with various graph visualizations.
I want to figure out whether a changeset X in branch "dev-X" was merged into another head of "dev-X". Therefore I cannot use branch names but only changeset numbers/hashes to specify a branch.

And to top it all, I'm trying to find out whether changeset X was transplanted there, possibly taking more than 1 transplantation step. I know that the necessary info is stored in mercurial (I've seen it when tampering with the mercurial internals), it's just not accessible via the command line interface.

Comment: Well, I gave it shot and this is what came out: http://bitbucket.org/resi/hg-contains/ . djc was right, it really wasn't too hard (at least, this code works with my repos).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above I gave it a shot, this is what came out:

http://bitbucket.org/resi/hg-contains/

Comment: Nice.  Mention this on the mercurial list, and add it to the extensions on the Mercurial wiki.

Comment: http://bitbucket.org/resi/hg-contains is gone.  [ContainsExtension on the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ContainsExtension) points to http://bitbucket.org/cashstar/hg-contains which is also gone.  Has the extension been abandoned or moved?

Comment: @Kevinoid long story short: I found a copy here: https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/re/resi/hg-contains.html . I cannot remember whether that was there were any additional changes but it appears to be quite ok.

Comment: Long version: I haven't used hg for quite some years, I guess it was 2015 since that was the last commit to this repo and around that time I left the company where hg was used. It seems that git already won the battle by then, all later jobs used git. I still think hg was better structured, there was a clear separation between working tree and repo data. Anyways, back then I transferred ownership of the bitbucket repo to that cashstar guys, in good faith since they seemed interested. Alas, they didn't care too much it seems. And bitbucket dropped hg for good. Still, the internet doesnt forget.

Comment: I'll try to put it up somewhere else, what's the favorite hg-bucket nowadays?

Comment: Thanks @resi!  I appreciate the sleuthing and explanation!  I actually don't use hg much these days either, so don't know about hosting.  The `hg log` commands (now added to [GitConcepts](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts)) were sufficient for my needs.  No need to invest more work on my account.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 18):

How about this:

```
hg log -r changeset_id -b branchname
```

That will give some output if `changeid_id` includes changes on branch `branchname`, otherwise no output is returned.

You could wrap it in a bash function if you want:

```
function contains() {
    if [ "$(hg log -r $1 -b $2)" == "" ]
    then
        echo no
    else
        echo yes
    fi
}
```

which does this:

```
$ contains 0 default
yes
$ contains 0 other   
no
```

Comment: Thats a very good solution for sane repos.
It doesn't work in my case though, where there are multiple heads for the most named branches.
Thinking about it, I should've mentioned that in the question ...

Comment: Resi, i think it still works so long as you're using named branches (which can still have multiple heads).  Every changeset has one and only one named branch associated with it -- "default" if you've never typed 'hg branches'.

That code just checks if the cset in question has the specified name as its 'branch' field.  It ignored heads (and tip) entirely and does work with multiple heads per named branch.

If you're not, however, using named branches (and I don't), then it's entirely useless because every changeset has 'default' in its branch property.

Comment: Ry4an: The presence of a given branch tag in a cset does not mean that this cset is part of any head of this branch. You could merge the branch (including this cset) into another branch, maybe "default", while keeping other versions of this branch alive.
This means that the cset we are looking for is tagged to belong to some branch but is actually only seen in the "default" branch.

Comment: Sounds like a divergence between what 'branch' means in your workflow and what it means in mercurial. Your request "tests whether a given changeset is in a branch" isn't about heads. In mercurial a changeset is very literally in a (named) branch if and only if the branch property on that changeset matches that name.

If you're talking about "is X an ancestor of one of many heads" then you're right to be looking at debugancestor. I've wrapped that:

function isKid() if [ $(hg debugancestor $1 $2 | cut -d : -f 1) == "$1" ] ; then echo $2 is a kid of $1; else echo $2 is NOT a kid of $1; fi

Comment: I guess you are right, my understanding of branches might differ from mercurial. Unfortunately my shell-fu isn't mentionable, this function seems like the shortest way to do the job...

Comment: As to your `isKid()` function — it uses revision number instead of changeset id which is what OP asks for. To use changest id instead it's enough to change `-f 1 ` to `-f 2`

Answer (score 15):

using 1.6 and later with the power of revision sets all you need is

```
hg log --rev "ancestors(.) and <revNum>"
```

eg

```
hg log --rev "ancestors(.) and 1234"
```

blank means no, output means yes, its in your history. Some of the other solutions posted here wont work if the changeset was created in a named branch, even if it was merged at some point later.

Comment: Pretty sure the `and revision` should be *outside* the `ancestors` call: `ancestors(.)` will create a set of all ancestors of the current revision, and `and` returns the intersection of 2 revsets. `. and 1234` will be an empty set unless `.` *is* `1234` so `ancestors(. and 1234)` will be the empty set unless `.` is `1234`. On the other hand, `ancestors(.) and 1234` will give the intersection of `ancestors(.)` and `set(1234)`, which is either `1234` if `1234` is an ancestor of `.` or an empty set if it's not.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349431/1127485) (which is using `descendants()` instead of 'ancestors()', but that shouldn't make a difference here).

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty easy to transform the results from debugancestor into a yes or a no (but there's definitely no built-in way to do that; write a script already!). Be aware that the answer might be wrong if the branch has more than one branch head, though.

(Writing an extension to add a command to do this should also be nigh-trivial, BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just print out the name of the branch for that revision (it'll be empty if it's default) and then test that against whatever you want (in bash or in a scripting language of some sort):

```
hg log --template '{branches}' -r <revision name/number>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested most of approaches above, did not work. The extension 'contains' somehow takes wrong revision (I think its a bug), the hg log --rev "ancestors(.) and 1234" work, but I found even more simple approach to do this:

`hg merge -P <changeset>`

Will show you if anything unmerged remains (it will also include changesets which are not merged parents of the changeset in question)