# What is hg syntax for: is commit A "reachable" from commit B

Tags: mercurial

The history of my repository is very complex. I often find myself wanting to know if a certain commit from the past "is in" or "is reachable from" a certain revision (usually one of my heads)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [revsets syntax](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets). Suppose you want to ask if revision 4 is "reachable" from revision 9.

Simply do this:

```
hg log -r "descendants(4) and 9"
```

if it is reachable, you will see the log message for revision 9. If it is not, there will be no output.

Comment: Inversed version of conditions|changests also possible: "ancestors() and" and defining complex condition as alias in [revsetalias], f.e alias `ip($1, $2) = ancestors($2) and $1` will allow write shorter revset -r "ip(4,9)"